# rubocop indent multiline assignment rule

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have the following code:

```
var = SomeLongClassName.new(foo)
                       .bar
                       .baz
```

How can I configure Rubocop to enforce the following indentation?

```
    var = SomeLongClassName.new(foo)
            .bar
            .baz
```

Comment: OMG. Why on the Earth would you enforce this? Besides anything else, leading dots are not IRB/Pry friendly when it gets to copy-paste.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I prefer leading dots in my code base as trailing dots are easy to miss and make it unclear as to if the next line is a continuation (chained) method call or an implicit receiver method call. When I post to SO obviously I change that mentality for the sake of copy paste. As for enforcement from a Rubocop perspective I can't say anything becuase I don't generally bother to allow an opinionated parser to dictate my programming style or execution

Comment: [with fixed indentation](https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/cops_layout/#layoutalignarguments) might be your friend.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin because I'm expected to follow it, it gets pointed out in pr reviews but it's not in our rubocop config. Personally, I dont think it's better or worse than other styles.

Comment: Re "implicit receiver method" if you enforced wrapping things in parens that might make that distinction cleaner. A standard style is more important than any particular preference, although I personally use trailing dots now as well. Used to be pro leading, for same reasoning as you. Never really ran into the problem tho, but I did get tired if reformatting every time I wanted to paste into a console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Layout/MultilineMethodCallIndentation)

From their docs:

```
myvariable = Thing
               .a
               .b
               .c
```